# Example of a non-abelian quotient of a non-abelian finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Give an example of a non-abelian quotient of a non-abelian finite
>   group.

This should be fairly simple but I am drawing a blank. I can think of plenty of non-abelian, finite groups but no non-abelian quotients..Is there a nice, simple example that meets this requirement?

Comment: You have been doing something very wrong if you are getting non-abelian quotients from abelian groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft oops I meant to say the opposite. I have edited the question!

Comment: Take the direct product of two nonabelian groups and use the projection homomorphism.

Comment: Any group is a quotient of itself.

Comment: Wait... did you mean an Abelian quotient of a non-Abelian group? Even then, the ideas shown here will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose your favorite nonabelian group $G$; then $G\times G$ is nonabelian and

$$(G\times G)/(1\times G)\cong G$$

Comment: Along the same lines, choose your favorite non-abelian group G, and ANY finite group A, whether abelian or non-abelian; G is a quotient of G x A.